# Packed array element assignment when using default

Tags: system-verilog

My array is declared and initialized to zero like this:

```
logic [7:0] example1 [4] = '{default : 4'h0};
```

I want to assign a specific bit of packed array to 'x' for all of the array elements, so I am using `default` clause. In this example we have 4 elements. I wanted to set example[ ][2] to x. i.e. example[0][2] = 'hx, example[1][2]='hx, example[2][2] = 'hx and so on.

updated the question after Toolic's answer:
I am just choosing bit 2 location as a example, but it can be any bit on-the fly.

I am expecting the output to look like this:

```
example[0][0]=0
example[0][1]=0
example[0][2]=x
example[0][3]=0
example[0][4]=0
example[0][5]=0
example[0][6]=0
example[0][7]=0
example[1][0]=0
example[1][1]=0
example[1][2]=x
example[1][3]=0
example[1][4]=0
example[1][5]=0
example[1][6]=0
example[1][7]=0
example[2][0]=0
example[2][1]=0
example[2][2]=x
example[2][3]=0
example[2][4]=0
example[2][5]=0
example[2][6]=0
example[2][7]=0
example[3][0]=0
example[3][1]=0
example[3][2]=x
example[3][3]=0
example[3][4]=0
example[3][5]=0
example[3][6]=0
example[3][7]=0
```

This is my executable code:

```
module m1;
logic [7:0] example1 [4] = '{default : 4'h0};
    initial begin
      example1 = '{default : {2'hx}};
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin
        for (int j=0; j < 8; j++) begin
          $display("example[%0d][%0d]=%0d",i,j,example1[i][j]);
        end
      end
    end
endmodule
```

However, `{2'hx}` makes the first two elements to go x and actual output look like this:

```
example[0][0]=x
example[0][1]=x
example[0][2]=0
example[0][3]=0
example[0][4]=0
example[0][5]=0
example[0][6]=0
example[0][7]=0
example[1][0]=x
example[1][1]=x
example[1][2]=0
example[1][3]=0
example[1][4]=0
example[1][5]=0
example[1][6]=0
example[1][7]=0
example[2][0]=x
example[2][1]=x
example[2][2]=0
example[2][3]=0
example[2][4]=0
example[2][5]=0
example[2][6]=0
example[2][7]=0
example[3][0]=x
example[3][1]=x
example[3][2]=0
example[3][3]=0
example[3][4]=0
example[3][5]=0
example[3][6]=0
example[3][7]=0
```

I am sure there must be a way to access only a specific bit of packed array when using default clause for other dimension. However, I can't figure out the syntax. Any help is appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an *assignment pattern* to make assignments to a particular element of an array, packed or unpacked. Assignment patterns must have values for all elements. And you cannot make assignments to non-contiguous elements of an array (usually called a *slice*).

The best way of handling this is using a foreach loop;

```
foreach (example1[i]) example1[i][specific_bit] = 'x;
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives me the output you are looking for:

```
module m1;
logic [7:0] example1 [4] = '{default: 8'b0000_0x00};
initial begin
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin
        for (int j=0; j < 8; j++) begin
          $display("example[%0d][%0d]=%0d",i,j,example1[i][j]);
        end
      end
end
endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 10.9.1 *Array assignment patterns*

This also works:

```
logic [7:0] example1 [4] = '{4{8'b0000_0x00}};
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't use 'default' during assignment as I already mentioned as part of my question. Reason being my array 'example1' need not be always 4 elements. I have provided value 4 for simplicity sake.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: oh sorry! I overlooked your solution. You did use default. For the sake of easiness I had to choose a bit, so I choose bit 2. Actually my requirement is that it can be arbitrary bit location. Let say a 64-bit length and I may have to choose assigning x on some bit out of these 64 bits. How do i make it generic?